# Managing a large amount of MBSA Results?

Tags: windows, audit

I am responsible for scanning and fixing issues on ~50 servers with Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer (MBSA) version 2.2. Unfortunately, there is no out of the box way to manage multiple MBSA results. The only semi-official way to do this has been through the [scripting examples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10750) page, and even this is not very great. It only sort of tallies the results up without giving details.

The best way I have come up with so far is changing the file extension of the MBSA results to XML and importing them into an excel spreadsheet but it is very tedious as it includes every detail, even if there is no issue, additionally this is suspicious to auditors who want "tamper free" results.

Is there a better method / procedure / program / trick to managing these results?

Answer (score 1):

There is the MBSA [Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180357.aspx) Pack from MS. It provides reports and performs some of the basic tasks an MBSA admin might need to do.

Comment: I cannot seem to find a working download link :(